# PyOpenGL: Cube Texture Is a Solid Color

Tags: python, opengl, textures, pyopengl

I was adding textures to a cube but kept running into this issue

[image]

I don't really know why this is happening and was wondering if anyone else could help.

Here are some of my code snippets:

Function to generate cube vertices.

```py
def cube_vertices(x, y, z, n):
    """ Return the vertices of the cube at position x, y, z with size 2*n."""
    return [
        [x+n,y-n,z-n], [x+n,y+n,z-n], [x-n,y+n,z-n], [x-n,y-n,z-n],
        [x+n,y-n,z+n], [x+n,y+n,z+n], [x-n,y-n,z+n], [x-n,y+n,z+n],
    ]
```

Function for generating a cube.

```py
def Cube(cubeverts):
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    for surf in surfs:
        for vertex in surf:
            glTexCoord2f(0.0,1.0)
            glVertex3fv(cubeverts[vertex])
    glEnd()
```

and a function to make the texture:

```py
def get_texture(texturename,width=16,height=16):
    img = Image.open(texturename)
    img_data = numpy.array(list(img.getdata()), numpy.int8)
    textID = glGenTextures(1)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textID)
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img_data)
    return textID
```

Comment: `glTexCoord2f(0.0,1.0)` So, all texture coords are the same?

Comment: whoops, I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding

```py
if n == 0:
    xv = 0.0
    yv = 0.0
if n == 1:
    xv = 1.0
    yv = 0.0
if n == 2:
    xv = 1.0
    yv = 1.0
if n == 3:
    xv = 0.0
    yv = 1.0
```

to the for vertex in surf loop

Final cube function:

```py
def Cube(cubeverts):
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    for surf in surfs:
        n = 0
        for vertex in surf:
            if n == 0:
                xv = 0.0
                yv = 0.0
            if n == 1:
                xv = 1.0
                yv = 0.0
            if n == 2:
                xv = 1.0
                yv = 1.0
            if n == 3:
                xv = 0.0
                yv = 1.0
            glTexCoord2f(xv,yv)
            glVertex3fv(cubeverts[vertex])
            n += 1
    glEnd()
```